# HTMX and AlpineJS conflicting on listening for a select change event

Tags: alpine.js, htmx

I'm trying to make HTMX and AlpineJS work together on a select element, what I expect:

- When user change select value it calls `/v2/Url?param=value&selectId=1`

What happens:

- It calls the url without appending `selectId` query parameter: `/v2/Url?param=value`

Best code that I can think of:

```
<select 
    name="selectId" 
    id="selectId"

    hx-get="/v2/Url?param=value"
    hx-target="#targetId" 

    x-data="{ disabled: false }"
    x-bind:disabled="disabled" 
    x-on:change="disabled = true" 
    x-on:htmx:after-on-load="disabled = false">

    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>


<div id="targetId">

</div>
```

When I remove the `x-on:change="disabled = true"` HTMx works fine, but when I add it, looks like HTMx stop listening for the `change` event.

Comment: Can you try with `x-on:change="$nextTick(() => disabled = true)"` to see if it works? it might give enough time to htmx to retrieve the value before you disable the input.

Comment: Worked! Now I see it, alpine was disabling it before htmx had a chance to get the value. Does alpine have any 'magic' directive to make this nextTick implicit or this is the best way?

Comment: No, you need to add the $nextTick yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [@Alejandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6905499/alejandro) comment I was able to solve this issue using alpine `$nextTick` function, final code:

```
<select 
    name="selectId" 
    id="selectId"

    hx-get="/v2/Url?param=value"
    hx-target="#targetId" 

    x-data="{ disabled: false }"
    x-bind:disabled="disabled" 
    x-on:change="$nextTick(() => disabled = true)"
    x-on:htmx:after-on-load="disabled = false">

    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>


<div id="targetId">

</div>
```